# Oxygen manufacturing on Mars

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I was reading about the Perseverance lander on Mars and was surprised to find that it has an oxygen manufacturing instrument on board. The oxygen is needed as a part of a binary rocket fuel to get back from Mars. It makes oxygen from carbon dioxide, a technology that would be very useful for carbon capture here on Earth. I can not find the chemistry or the technology that makes this work. Does anybody know the chemistry of this instrument?

The following is the text from [nasa.gov](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-perseverance-mars-rover-extracts-first-oxygen-from-red-planet) explaining the mechanism of MOXIE:

> Mars’ atmosphere is 96% carbon dioxide. MOXIE works by separating
> oxygen atoms from carbon dioxide molecules, which are made up of one
> carbon atom and two oxygen atoms. A waste product, carbon monoxide, is
> emitted into the Martian atmosphere.

Comment: Carbon capture is not about chemistry at all. The real problem is "where is the money".

Comment: It would only be a useful process if the energy cost of doing it were remotely reasonable (heck, if we did it now we'd probably need to burn even *more* fossil fuel to generate the energy, releasing even more CO2 than we'd consume by the process!)

Comment: If you really wish to see the details, see this article: Mars Oxygen ISRU Experiment (MOXIE), it has all the pictures that you will ever need. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-020-00782-8

Comment: The abstract in this link has some details of the process  -  https://www.nature.com/articles/s41560-019-0457-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [this site](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/instruments/moxie/for-scientists/), Nasa give some closer information on the MOXIE system.
It splits electrochemically $\ce{2 CO2}$ into $\ce{2 CO}$ and $\ce{O2}$.

Comment: There must be a catalyst involved.

Comment: I think we are talking about the principle of a solide ocide electrolyzer which is roughtly explained here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxide_electrolyzer_cell

Comment: For this to be a good answer it should include the details of how the process works: link-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: I am sorry but the question was, which chemical principal is behind it. The principal is electrochemical split via a solid oxide electrolyzer cell. This could be found with an easy online research. If he is looking for a detailed description of the process, which preasure temperature, which currency, voltage etc. than I expect to do some research before and then ask a more precise question.